# How to create cleaner urls with CodeIgniter's routes?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to convert urls that look like this http://example.com/account?username=theUsername to look more like this http://example.com/account/theUsername. How is this possible, am using CodeIgniter as my framework.

Comment: this is pretty basic CodeIgniter stuff here.  You should probably go through the tutorial on their website: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter, in defult comes with pretty urls like incase you turned on the query string in config:

www.site.com/user/jefferson

You can take a look at

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html